# only able to boot into Ubuntu after update. dual boot screen not showing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, windows-10, bios

I have windows 10 installed alongside Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. In the past, it has worked flawlessly. Currently, only ubuntu will load.

I had some recent security updates with my Ubuntu. After installing them I no longer see the dual boot screen. Instead, it auto-starts Ubuntu every time I start the computer.

I no longer see any start-up screen until ubuntu is fully loaded

I tried to use F2, F10, and F12 to access the BIOS but when I press them the computer monitor will not show and will go into power-saving mode as if the computer is off even though it is on.

Comment: Any recent to the Windows install?

Comment: I used boot-repair from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Now I see the BIOs but it skips grub2 and goes straight to windows.  It fixed one problem but gave me a different problem

Comment: @David nothing out of the norm for Windows.

Comment: In a terminal run this command sudo update-grub